# is it possible to set order of tkinter entries in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I have a dictionary with all entries where I want to put some changes at once. I need to keep to order as it is set in dictionary, but after proceeding the loop my dictionary changes the order of items. I'm not sure if keys or orderedDict will help here. Appreciate for help.

```
list_of_entries = {self.entry_Owner,self.entry_price,self.entry_name,self.entry_Description}
```

Comment: If you're not sure if OrderedDict will help, why not try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are not using Python 3.7, as in this version, a `dict` is now guaranteed to remember the order in which entries were added.

However, before dictionaries were explicitly not ordered, which is probably your case. As you apparently don't want to order the keys in an alphabetic order or something like that, receiving the keys of your dictionary with `.keys()` and sorting them won't help.

For this, the `collections.OrderedDict` does indeed help. You can create a new ordered dictionary with `OrderedDict(((key1, value1), (key2, value2)))` and so on. Afterwards you will be able to work with the dictionary like with a normal one, i.e. e.g. indexing and assigning works the same.

As I'm not sure as to what values you want to insert in your dictionary (what are `self.entry_Owner` and so on), I am not able to give you a more concrete answer, but this should help you out.